# Printing on the same line as a header in python

Tags: python

I am writing a function calculate a score for the matrix and output the score along with some other variables as a header. My code for output is as follows:

```
header=">"+motif+" "+gene+" "+str(score)
append_copy = open(newpwmfile, "r")
original_text = append_copy.read()
append_copy.close()
append_copy = open(newpwmfile, "w")
append_copy.write(header)
append_copy.write(original_text)
append_copy.close()
```

However the header is printing the score on the next line instead of the same line, as follows:

```
    >ATGC ABC/CDF
     5.8
     0.23076923076923   0   0.69230769230769    0.076923076923077
     0.46153846153846   0.23076923076923    0.23076923076923  0.076923076923077
     0  0   1   0
     0  1   0   0
     1  0   0   0
```

What could be the reason? I also tried interchanging the variables and then the header is printed on the same line. However the sequence is relevant in this case.

Comment: What value does score have?

Comment: My guess is that the string `gene` has a newline in it. Try `gene.strip()`

Comment: It worked! thanks @EricAppelt it was the gene variable!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `header`?

Answer (score 2):

When reading fields from a file, it is good practice to remove possible extra blank spaces using `strip()` function.

As an example, this is a typical workflow to manually get the fields from a csv file:

```
for line in open(fname).readlines():
    linefields = [field.strip() for field in line.strip().split(',')]
```

This removes either the blankspace between lines and the blankspace between fields.